# Combobox not accepting assigned value

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have ajax combobox in vb.net aspx page, on page load, I am assigning a value to combobox box, eg

combobox1.text = "abc"

but it does not accept this value and reverts to default value. the value I am assigning is not an item of the combobox.

here is some code: in aspx page

```
                <cc1:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFEA" Font-Bold="True" Height="25px" Width="300px">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">customer</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>client</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>applicant</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>student</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>patient</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>citizen</asp:ListItem>
                </cc1:ComboBox>
```

in page_Load

If IsNothing(servedTitle) = False Then ComboBox1.Text = servedTitle

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Set DropDownStyle = DropDown.

Comment: tried that, still does not accept value assigned on page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select something that's not in the list.  You'll have to add the item.  Then select it.

```
If ComboBox1.Items.FindByValue(servedTitle) Is Nothing Then
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(servedTitle)
End If
ComboBox1.Text = servedTitle
```

Comment: but as a combobox, its supposed to accept a value given by user that may not be in list.

Comment: Should I be using a different control instead?

Comment: Right, the user can type in their own value.  However, your example shows trying to select a value programmatically before it's served to the user.  To do that you need to use Items.Add() if the item isn't in the list.